# Implementation of Task Manager

Tags: c++

I have implemented some basic functionalities of task manager wherein whenever a new process is created it will be added to list of processes. Also if any process creates thread(s) it will get added to the thread list which is per process.

ProcessManager.h

```
#ifndef DLP_PROCESS_MANAGER_H
#define DLP_PROCESS_MANAGER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <mutex>

#include "Process.h"

class ProcessManager {
    ProcessManager() = default;
    ~ProcessManager() = default;

public:
    ProcessManager(const ProcessManager&) = delete;
    ProcessManager& operator=(const ProcessManager&) = delete;
    ProcessManager(ProcessManager&&) = delete;
    ProcessManager& operator=(ProcessManager&&) = delete;

    std::timed_mutex processListMutex;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Process> processList;

    static ProcessManager& getInstance();
    void addProcess(const std::string& processID, std::vector<std::string>&& threadIDList);
    void startProcessThreads(const std::string& processID);
    void updateProcessData(const std::string& processID, double CPU, double memory);
    void clearAll();
};

#endif //DLP_PROCESS_MANAGER_H
```

ProcessManager.cpp

```
#include "ProcessManager.h"

ProcessManager& ProcessManager::getInstance() {
    static ProcessManager processManager;

    return processManager;
}

void ProcessManager::addProcess(const std::string& processID, std::vector<std::string>&& threadIDList) {
    std::lock_guard<std::timed_mutex> processListMutexGuard(processListMutex);

    auto& processData = processList[processID];
    processData.processID = processID;

    for (auto& threadID : threadIDList) {
        auto& thread = processData.threadList[threadID];
        thread.threadID = threadID;
        thread.processID = processID;
    }
}

void ProcessManager::startProcessThreads(const std::string& processID) {
    std::lock_guard<std::timed_mutex> processListMutexGuard(processListMutex);

    auto itr = processList.find(processID);
    if (itr != std::end(processList)) {
        for (const auto& ent : itr->second.threadList)
            itr->second.startThread(ent.first);
    }
}

void ProcessManager::updateProcessData(const std::string& processID, double CPU, double memory) {
    std::lock_guard<std::timed_mutex> processListMutexGuard(processListMutex);

    auto itr = processList.find(processID);
    if (itr != std::end(processList))
        itr->second.updateProcessData(CPU, memory);
}

void ProcessManager::clearAll() {
    std::lock_guard<std::timed_mutex> processListMutexGuard(processListMutex);

    for (auto& pent : processList) {
        for (auto& tent : pent.second.threadList) {
            tent.second.enableTermination();
            tent.second.wait();
            std::cout << "Process " << tent.second.processID << ":" << tent.second.threadID << " stopped" << std::endl;
        }
        pent.second.threadList.clear();
    }

    processList.clear();
}
```

Process.h

```
#ifndef DLP_PROCESS_H
#define DLP_PROCESS_H

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

#include "Thread.h"

class Process {
public:
    Process() = default;
    ~Process() = default;

    std::string processID;
    double CPU {}, memory {};
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Thread> threadList;

    void startThread(const std::string& threadID);
    void updateProcessData(double CPU, double memory);
};

#endif //DLP_PROCESS_H
```

Process.cpp

```
#include "Process.h"

void Process::startThread(const std::string& threadID) {
    auto itr = threadList.find(threadID);
    if (itr != std::end(threadList))
        itr->second.start();
}

void Process::updateProcessData(double CPU, double memory) {
    this->CPU = CPU;
    this->memory = memory;
}
```

Thread.h

```
#ifndef DLP_THREAD_H
#define DLP_THREAD_H

#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

class Thread {
    std::thread th;
    std::atomic_bool terminateFlag {};

public:
    Thread() = default;
    ~Thread() = default;

    std::string threadID;
    std::string processID;

    void enableTermination();
    void start();
    void run();
    void wait();
};

#endif //DLP_THREAD_H
```

Thread.cpp

```
#include "Thread.h"
#include "ProcessManager.h"

void Thread::enableTermination() {
    terminateFlag = true;
}

void Thread::start() {
    th = std::thread(&Thread::run, this);
}

void Thread::run() {
    while (!terminateFlag) {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        // {
            // std::lock_guard<std::timed_mutex> processListMutexGuard(ProcessManager::getInstance().processListMutex);
         if (ProcessManager::getInstance().processListMutex.try_lock_for(100ms)) {
            // access process data
            Process& process = ProcessManager::getInstance().processList[processID];
            // std::cout << "thread " << threadID << " of process " << processID << " CPU: " << process.CPU << ", Memory: " << process.memory << std::endl;
            ProcessManager::getInstance().processListMutex.unlock();
        }
        // do further process
    }
}

void Thread::wait() {
    th.join();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "ProcessManager.h"

int main() {
    ProcessManager::getInstance().addProcess("p1", {"p1t1", "p1t2", "p1t3", "p1t4"});
    ProcessManager::getInstance().addProcess("p2", {"p2t1", "p2t2", "p2t3", "p2t4"});
    ProcessManager::getInstance().addProcess("p3", {"p3t1", "p3t2", "p3t3", "p3t4"});
    ProcessManager::getInstance().addProcess("p4", {"p4t1", "p4t2", "p4t3", "p4t4"});
    ProcessManager::getInstance().addProcess("p5", {"p5t1", "p5t2", "p5t3", "p5t4"});

    ProcessManager::getInstance().startProcessThreads("p1");
    ProcessManager::getInstance().startProcessThreads("p2");
    ProcessManager::getInstance().startProcessThreads("p3");
    ProcessManager::getInstance().startProcessThreads("p4");
    ProcessManager::getInstance().startProcessThreads("p5");

    ProcessManager::getInstance().updateProcessData("p1", 1, 64);
    ProcessManager::getInstance().updateProcessData("p2", 2, 128);
    ProcessManager::getInstance().updateProcessData("p3", 4, 256);
    ProcessManager::getInstance().updateProcessData("p4", 16, 512);
    ProcessManager::getInstance().updateProcessData("p5", 32, 1024);

    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);

    ProcessManager::getInstance().clearAll();
}
```

Also I'm trying to replace manual locking and unlocking of mutex in the `run` method of `Thread` class by `std::lock_guard`, but facing a deadlock issue.

Comment: What is the purpose of the Process class? Does it represent a thread pool?

Comment: @panik A process can have multiple threads and it just stores them in a list, so that when I send a process terminate request it will wait for all the threads to terminate(basically a proper cleanup happens).

Answer (score 1):

`processListMutex` acts like a global lock by serializing all running threads.
Of course, a sort of global locking may be necessary to protect a program output.
But it suffices to define one mutex per process to access the process shared data.

---

Clearly, we have a hierarchy of entities, but the code design lacks separation of concerns.
Not only `Thread` interacts with `ProcessManager` through the mutex, also `ProcessManager` interacts with `Thread` directly.
It is called `ProcessManager`, right?

---

`processListMutex` and `processList` should be private.
Otherwise, we can make them static and remove the singleton.
I suggest making the manager a regular class because there is no actual need to have only one manager.
Some developers regard singleton as an antipattern.
You may be interested in checking some implementations of design patterns in C++ ([wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns), [refactoring](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/cpp), [cpppatterns](https://cpppatterns.com/)).

---

`getInstance` is annoyingly wordy.
There is no 'instance' field in the class, so we can cut short it to `instance` which is sort of conventional.

---

`Process` requires a destructor to ensure proper termination of threads in all execution scenarios.
A thread pool would have something like this

```
~ThreadPool() {
    for (auto& t : threads) {
        if (t.joinable())
            t.join();
    }
}
```

In the present terms,

```
void Thread::wait() {
    if (th.joinable())
        th.join();
}

~Process() {
    for (auto& [_, t] : threadList) {
        t.wait();
    }
}
```

If an `std::thread` object is destructed before the managed (by the object) execution thread is joined, the program has undefined behavior.

The requirement is necessary to enforce [the core C++ RAII principle](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-raii).
At the moment, thread resources are managed manually by means of the `clearAll` function.

---

`Process` data members are meant to be shared among the process threads and the `ProcessManager`, yet the update method does not secure data.

---

A possible deadlock scenario. For `m` - main thread, `t` - an arbitrary manually created thread,

- `m` calls `clearAll` and successfully acquires the mutex
- `m` is interrupted by the scheduler before raising the `t.terminationFlag`
- `t` sees `terminationFlag == false` and tries to acquire the mutex. Gets locked by the `lock_guard`.
- `m` wakes up, raises the flag and waits for `t` to `join`. Gets locked consequently.

---

I recommend you checking the book "C++ Concurrency in Action" by Williams.
It will most likely help you to solve all the issues.
You may find there a detailed explanation of sample thread pool implementation.